# Gradle Maven Depedency

Tags: javascript, maven, continuous-integration, gradle

I am new to gradle/maven and I want to apply it to my javascript project.

I have one main project and 2 subprojects. Each subproject will create a zip package and deploy to nexus. 
So the mainProject is in fact to publish all the subprojects only.

```
  MainProject/   
    SubProject1/   
    SubProject2/   
    build.gradle   
    gradle.properties   
    settings.gradle
```

In fact SubProject2 will depend on SubProject1 when load that subproject1. However, they are independent in publish stage. So I have no idea where to put the dependency. I should add the dependencies to the pom file when publish? like pom.withXml or define in the gradle (but it is irrelevant at publish)?

```
subprojects {
    //to package the file
    task packageFile (type:Zip){
        from 'src'
    }

    publishing {
        publications {
            maven(MavenPublication) {
                groupId project.group
                artifact packageFile
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In gradle, the SubProjects are referred as modules. 
You project is a multi-module project.
In your case, each module is an independent artifact.
Each module has its own build.gradle file, in which you can set the module/artifact properties.
In the project level build.gradle you can set the common properties (e.g. the group Id).
Since you have a dependency between your modules AND each is an artifact, you need to define dependency instead of compile project(:module1) as a 3rd party dependency.
Since you also need the dependency to be tight during development, you need that each build  will install them to local repository & set gradle to refresh/check those dependencies state continuously.